# how can I run a .jar file when it doesn't open up when clicked on and can't run it through the cmd?

Tags: java, jar, windows-10-universal

Can't open the .jar file. Have the latest version of java installed. Tried opening from the command line also but failed to do so. Please help.

Comment: Please describe what happened when you opened cmd window and typed `java -jar JAR_NAME`. Double click may or may not work

Comment: What does “failed to do so” mean?  Did your fingers go numb? Did your computer catch fire?  What actually happened?

Comment: java -jar command did not work from the cmd. Gave an error I guess saying java not installed or something. I saved that command as a .bat file and it worked